# Is it possible to set unique constraint to the subset of all rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique

I'm in `PostgreSQL 9.4`. I have the following table:

```
   id           name                 deleted
seril PK      varchar(32)        boolean NOT NULL
```

Is it possible to apply `UNIQUE` constraint to all rows with `deleted = false`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a partial index.

From documentation

> When the WHERE clause is present, a partial index is created. A partial index is an index that contains entries for only a portion of a table, usually a portion that is more useful for indexing than the rest of the table. For example, if you have a table that contains both billed and unbilled orders where the unbilled orders take up a small fraction of the total table and yet that is an often used section, you can improve performance by creating an index on just that portion. Another possible application is to use WHERE with UNIQUE to enforce uniqueness over a subset of a table. See Section 11.8 for more discussion.

Reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createindex.html

Just to add an example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX yourindexname onyourtable (id)
WHERE deleted = false;
```

This is supported since version 7.2 of Postgresql.

Comment: Is that supported in the 8.4 version?

Comment: @user3663882: It's supported for a very long time, including version 8.4. By the way, 8.4 is EOL, not supported anymore. Advice: Upgrade to a recent version.

Comment: Version 7.2, February 2002.

Comment: I confirm 7.2 version. Just an hint. In the documentation page you can see links to older or newer version for the same argument. So you can check for the required version.

Comment: @user3663882 I updated answer with version information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think the question on 8.4 is just informative. User wrote: PostgreSQL 9.4.  in the question.